# CodeIgniter DB and getting two values

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I have ONE input text field and the user can enter a first name, last name, id, email or phone number and it will get that the rest of the users information. However when a user tries to enter a first and last name like Jerry Smith (and this has been happening alot) I get a null value.

What can I do so if the user enters both a first and last name it will return the person and not null.

Here is my code....

```
            //$id = 1234;
            //$phone = '555-555-5555';
            //$email = 'test@email.com';
            //$firstname = 'Jerry';
            //$lastname = 'Smith';
              $fullname = 'Jerry Smith';

            if($id || $phone || $email || $firstname || $lastname) {
                    $data = get_user_info($id, $phone, $email, $firstname, $lastname);
            }

            function get_user_info($id = null, $phone = null, $email = null, $firstname = null, $lastname = null){
            if($id) {
                    $this->db->or_where('ID', $id);
            }
            if($phone) {
                    $this->db->or_where('HomePhone', $phone);
            }
            if($email) {
                    $this->db->or_where('HomeEmail', $email);
            }
            if($firstname) {
                    $this->db->or_where('FirstName', $firstname);
            }
            if($lastname) {
                    $this->db->or_where('LastName', $lastname);
            }
            $query = $this->db->get($this->my_table);
            $member = $query->result_array();
            return $member;
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have but first I have to ask, have you tried testing this with data that you know exists? A valid first and last name?

Comment: i assume you get your values with input class post method so try comparing like; `$id !== FALSE`

Comment: @rcpayan that won't work because the input is a string. So if he wants to compare 'John Smith' against the first name, unless the first name is 'John Smith' he will always get NULL. He needs to break up the input.

Comment: but he said he gets first name and surname from form input seperately that's why i offered thats

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_user_info($id = null, $phone = null, $email = null, $firstname = null, $lastname = null)
{
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->where('ID',$id);
     $this->db->or_where('HomePhone',$phone);
     $this->db->or_where('HomeEmail',$email);
     $this->db->or_where('FirstName',$firstname);
     $this->db->or_where('LastName',$lastname);
     $query = $this->db->get($this->my_table);
     $member = $query->result_array();
     return $member;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split up the input text by space using `explode()` and moving your if checks into a `foreach` loop? Example:

```
$input = explode(' ', $input_field);

foreach ($input as $i) {
    if ($i == 'first_name') //do something
    if ($i == 'last_name') //do something
}
```

Right now you're just checking whatever the user inputs so the odds of getting `NULL` are high.

As a side note you should probably validate the input a bit more before you run it against the database. Even though CodeIgniter will automatically escape your queries for you, it's a good practice.